# Prove or disprove if set is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove: The set Y of numbers in (0,1) with a decimal expansion that contains only 0s and 1s, and only finitely many 0s, is an uncountable set.

Uncountable means it's not finite or not denumerable. It seems that this would not be finite, since there may be unlimited 1s in the decimal expansion. Denumerable means that it's a bijection.

I'd appreciate any help on this. I'm kind of struggling on how to get started on these proofs. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: these are all rationals.

Comment: hint. How many sequences of finite length are there? For each of your numbers consider the largest finite subsequence that ends in 0. What does this question have to do with linear algebra?

Comment: Stories About Sets by V'Lenkin.

Comment: Hint 2: What possible bijection *with the natural numbers* could you try?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews all numbers described by the OP are rational numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews BrianO meant they were *a subset of the rationals*.  Not that they were identical sets.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you — right, these don't exhaust the rationals in $(0,1)$, but every $y\in Y$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

The key aspect of uncountability proofs is proving that the set cannot
be injective to the Naturals (even if surjective), or show that it
is bijective to the reals. I would imagine that the later would be a
bit more finicky, so assume for the sake of contradiction that it
is injective to the naturals. Is there some kind of pigeon-hole
principle I can do with the injective function to say that it
is *not* injective? I.e. use pigeon-hole principle to show that two
items in $(0,1)$ must point to the same item in $\mathbb{N}$? That is
the essence of this problem.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question